Invalid value for param; wrong type or other syntax error: timeIntervals LinkedIn API
I want to get my metric share statistics from my page LinkedIn, the docs in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?view=li-lms-2024-06&tabs=curl
I tried in postman is working well, but when i implement to my code (i'm using PHP) is getting error:
{   "errorDetailType": "com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest",   "message": "Invalid param. Please see errorDetails for more information.",   "errorDetails": {     "inputErrors": [       {         "description": "Invalid value for param; wrong type or other syntax error",         "input": {           "inputPath": {             "fieldPath": "timeIntervals"           }         },         "code": "PARAM_INVALID"       }     ]   },   "status": 400 }
Here is my code:
$date_start = strtotime(date('Y-01-01 00:01:01'));
$date_end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Linkedin-Version' => '202406',
            'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
        ])->get('https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics', [
            'q' => 'organizationalEntity',
            'organizationalEntity' => 'urn:li:organization:XXXXXXXX',
            'timeIntervals' => '(timeGranularityType:DAY,timeRange:(start:'.$date_start.',end:'.$date_end.'))',
        ]);
        return $response->json();

When i do $date_start & $date_end in hardcode like:
$date_start = 1704067200000;
$date_end = 1717113600000;

the result is still same error
But, when im not using timeIntervals params, is working well
What's wrong with my code?
Thank you so much for you who answered and help me.

I presume you should pass 'timeIntervals.timeGranularityType' => 'DAY' etc.

@u_mulder omg u trigger saving my life. The params it should be 'timeIntervals.timeGranularityType' => 'DAY' , timeIntervals.timeRange.start => $date_start , timeIntervals.timeRange.end => $date_end . Using Restli 1.0 on the docs. So in postman using Restli 2.0 but in code using Restli 1.0. Thank you so much

@u_mulder and dont using 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0', in header
